# Asus notebook doesn't boot with new memory

Tags: laptop, memory

I have installed new memory into notebook, but it doesn't boot. When I turn power on, only green light turns on. Everything seems to match: slot is DDR3 SO-DIMM, motherboard memory frequency is 1333MHz, which is supported by memory stick according to specs. Unfortunately I'm not able to test memory in another notebook. I have updated BIOS, but the problem still remains.

Is there a memory defect, or have I missed something and the memory doesn't suit?

```
Notebook: ASUS X551MAV-BING-SX374B
Motherboard: X551MA rev.2
Processor: Intel N2830
Memory: Corsair CMSX4GX3M1A1600C9
```

Comment: How large are these modules precisely?  Unless you test the modules in another device we can't really say if they are defective.  *That is something you have to tell us.*

Comment: If your motherboard has several DDR slots, try them all.

Comment: @Roman motherboard has only one DDR3 slot

Comment: @Ramhound The memory module is 4GB

Comment: What makes you think it's suppose to boot with 4GB modules installed?

Answer (score 1):

I think your new memory module mustn't work in your laptop because:

1. Your processor *Intel Celeron N2830* requires **DDR3L** memory modules ("L" is for "lower voltage" - **1.35V** instead of 1.5V). http://ark.intel.com/products/81071/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N2830-1M-Cache-up-to-2_41-GHz
2. Your new memory module *Corsair CMSX4GX3M1A1600C9* requires 1.5 voltage http://www.corsair.com/en-us/vengeance-4gb-high-performance-sodimm-memory-upgrade-kit-cmsx4gx3m1a1600c9
   Quote from this Corsair page:

> If your notebook uses a 4th Generation Intel Core processor, you should use one of our 1.35 Volt Vengeance memory kits.